# how webrtc from mobile(Android) to PC(Web)

Tags: webrtc

I conunter a problem,
   I want transfer video from mobile(Android) to PC(Web) using WebRTC, it works well when Both mobile and PC have camera, but it not work when PC don't have camera. Is the peerconnection means both side need the some source?
   is anyone can give me suggestions or some demos?
   Thanks a lot!

Comment: Most probably you're trying to obtain the stream with `getUserMedia` that's why a camera is needed.

Answer (score 0):

WebRTC and its PeerConnection don't mandate the use of a camera.

Something you are doing in your own code is forcing that and/or causing the session to fail.